# Jquery (easySlider) - one click, slide two divs

Tags: jquery, easyslider

I have downloaded the JQuery plugin [EasySlider1.7](http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider). I have the basics working but I'd like to expand.

I would like to click the <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd> arrows and have the `div id="logo"` animate simultaneously as the image div that is presently animating.

Here's the [link](http://febrey.com/new%20site/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following html:

```
<span id="prevBtn1">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</span>
<span id="nextBtn1">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</span>
```

To：

```
<span >
<a id="prevBtn1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</span>
<span>
<a  id="nextBtn1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Had to go in to the .js to make that fix, but it worked!  Thanks you.